# return no stopping controller action for remote call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.5

I have an issue with a form sendind two parameters to a controller. I would like that the `erb.js`template not be triggered if the `update` of the object fails.

I have added `return` at the end of my action but the view is still triggered.

Her is the bit of my controller which I think is responsible for actionning the view or not :

```
if @object.update(some_params)

...
  respond_to do |f|
    f.html {redirect_to some_path_here}
    f.js
  end
end

return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happens, because according to [convention over configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action) `Rails` automatically renders action view, if not explicitly specified.

In order to avoid rendering, one of the options would be setting head if `@object` hasn't been successfully updated:

```
if @object.update(some_params)

...
  respond_to do |f|
    f.html {redirect_to some_path_here}
    f.js
  end
else
  head :unprocessable_entity
end
```

Comment: Actually inside the `if` statement the view is rendered correctly. It's outside the condition that the `return` is not really effective. Unfortunately changing the `respond_to` method as you suggest has no effect. (actually I want that the view not to be rendered by default, only if the condition statement is successful.... Maybe it's not a good design)

Comment: @Maxence ah, didn't understand your purpose. then you can specify `head` instead of the `return` keyword, that you've tried. updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for this. But now view is not rendered but it is not rendered either if the condition is true (and `update` of object pass). Maybe I should render the view explicitly in the `respond_to` and add `and return` ? (sorry not very familiar with `head` method)

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Though why `return` didn't work and have to play with head ?

Comment: the link, I've provided, actually explains it https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action

Comment: you need either explicitly render a view (or specify head without content) or let Rails to render it according to the convention